# Showing/Hiding Banners in Unity 5.1 and AdMob plugin 2.3 after some time won't hide banner or even load it, any idea why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I integrated AdMob in my Unity project where banners are supposed to be displayed at menu and game over screen. Problem is that after some time banner ether wont hide any more or stops from showing up.

Here is a code for requesting and showing/hiding banners:

```
    bool    bannertrigger = false;
    public float bannerRequestTimeout;
    float bannerRequestedTime;
    float bannerSakrivanjeVreme;




void Start(){
        RequestBanner();
        bannerRequestedTime = Time.time;

    }
void Update(){


        if (Time.time > bannerRequestedTime + bannerRequestTimeout) {
            RequestBanner ();
            bannerRequestedTime = Time.time;
        }

        if ((GameController.pause || GameController.gameOver !=0) && !bannertrigger) {
            bannerView.Show ();
            bannertrigger = true;
            Debug.Log (bannertrigger);



        }

        if (!GameController.pause && GameController.gameOver == 0 && bannertrigger) {
                bannerView.Hide();
                bannertrigger = false;
            Debug.Log (bannertrigger);


        }
}
```

}

Debug log shows that if statements works like they are supposed to do, so the problem is somewhere in bannerView.Show() and  bannerView.Hide() but I have no idea what to do anymore. What am I doing wrong?

GameController.pause is bool (true if paused)
GameController.gameOver is int (!= 0 if game over)